# find the max value of column 1 and print respective record from column 2 from file

Tags: shell, shell-script, scripting

How to find the max value from the column 1 and echo the respective path location from a file which contains n number of records.

```
$ cat version.log
112030  /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0
121010  /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0
```

Expected output:

```
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should work:

```
awk -v max=0 '{if($1>max){want=$2; max=$1}}END{print want} ' version.log
```

The `-v max=0` sets the variable `max` to `0`, then, for each line, the first field is compared to the current value of `max`. If it is greater, `max` is set to the value of the 1st field and `want` is set to the current line. When the program has processed the entire file, the current value of `want` is printed.

**Edit**

I did not test the `awk` solution earlier and it was really my bad to have provided it. Anyways, the edited version of the answer should work (Thanks to terdon for fixing it) and I tested the below as well.

```
sort -nrk1,1 filename | head -1 | cut -d ' ' -f3
```

I am `sort`ing on the first field where,

- -n specifies numerical sort.
- -r specifies reverse the sort result.
- -k1,1 specifies first field for the sorting to occur.

Now, after the sorting I am piping the output and just getting the first result which will give me the numerically highest value of column1 in the result.

Now, I finally pipe it to `cut` with the delimiter specified as space and printing the `-f3` which is the intended output.

**Testing**

```
cat filename
112030   /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0
121010   /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0
2312     /hello/some/other/path
3423232  /this/is/really/big/number
342      /ok/not/the/maximum/number
9999899  /Max/number
9767     /average/number
```

Now, after I run the above command for the input as above, I get the output as,

```
/Max/number
```

Comment: awk max doesn't compare string field numerically. is that why you gave a second approach?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it with `AWK`.

```
$ awk '{if(max<$1){max=$1;line=$2}}END{print line}' file 
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0
```

Here first column of each line is compared with the variable `max` (which is initially 0). If the first column has a value greated that `max` then the second column is stored in the variable `line`, this continues for each and every line of the file.

At the end of the file `END` rule is executed to print the `line` variable.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '$1 > max { max = $1; output = $2 } END { print output }' version.log
```

Answer (score 3):

`sort -k1 -n filename | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: This should work but is inefficient, because sorting is overkill when the task is to find a maximum.

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can sort it by using `sort` command

```
sort -r version.log | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Output:

```
/opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/12.1.0
```

Comment: you want to print the second value only 

try this cat version.log | sort -r | head -n1 | awk -F " " '{Print $2}'

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your terminal. Just paste the text instead. Also, there's no need for `cat`, sort can take input files directly.